Standardizing between time sensitive datasets
I have two datasets for property values in 2020 and 2024, in which I've created two separate models to predict property value. I want to compare the output of these models by using the mean absolute error (MAE). The challenge here is that property values have risen by some percentage between 2020 and 2024, so the MAE in the 2024 model will naturally be higher as a consequence of raising property values. How can I standardize the two datasets to better compare MAE?
Does it make sense to standardize 2020, then apply that transformation to 2024 and recalculate the MAE?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
